# If else query, so the user cannot input higher than the quantity left

Tags: php, mysql

Additional if else query so that the user cant input higher than the stock.

I want to add an if else query where in the user cannot input higher than the stocks , what would be the best approach.

This is my code

```
<?php

    include('session.php');
    if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $qty=$_POST['qty'];

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
            echo "Product already on your cart!";
        }   
        else{
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cart (userid, productid, qty) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id', '$qty')");
        }
    }

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to fetch the quantity of stock left for that particular productid - probably from some sort of product table.  Without the table names etc. it's difficult to do much more.

Comment: Tried adding this else if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < $qty){
   echo "Invalid Input ( Input must be lower than the quantity)!"; but it accepts lower numbers as higher than the qty

Comment: This is a little tricky. The user needs to know the availability, but this value can only ever be an approximation because at any given moment another user may have purchased some of that remaining stock (or possibly sold stock, thereby increasing availability). So you need one (ideally asynchronous) check for approximate availability, and another check on insertion that the number entered is purchasable. In the event of a mismatch between these figures you need to consider whether to reserve available stock while the user decides what to do next

Comment: Imagine that the last item is left on the stock and two users make in the same moment the order, also with the check they would buy it twice! You need a __transaction__ and also **locking** the table